# running docker commands from a bash script has different results

Tags: docker, openvswitch

I use the [socketplane/openvswitch](https://hub.docker.com/r/socketplane/openvswitch/) docker image.
When I follow their instructions to build and execute OVS commands in a running container, everything works fine. However, when I try to build a bash script for running and executing OVS commands the container returns with

```
db.sock: Database connection failed (Connection refused)
```

Actually the problem is running the following commands in a terminal:

```
docker run -itd --cap-add NET_ADMIN [container-name]
docker exec $cid ovs-vsctl show
```

succeeds, but running same commands in a bash script does not.

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cid=$(docker run -itd --cap-add NET_ADMIN [container-name])
docker exec $cid ovs-vsctl show
```

Thanks

Comment: We can't answer this without more detail. At the very least a reference to what instructions you're following to cause the problem. And what (sequence of) commands you're running that error.

Comment: [ask] is a useful reference point for making a good question. Imagine I'm trying to reproduce your fault on my system. What would I need to do?

Comment: sorry, modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought would be that the root of your problem is here:

```
docker run -itd
```

Because they're contradictory parameters.

- `-d` says 'run in background`.
- `-it` says 'run interactively, attach a tty.

So I would suggest that you try:

```
#!/bin/bash
cid=$(docker run -d --cap-add NET_ADMIN [container-name])
docker exec $cid ovs-vsctl show
```

Failing that, my second guess would be - the startup process of the container takes a little while. I get this when firing up `kibana` containers - it takes a few seconds to start, so I get 'permission denied' errors.

Try sticking a 'sleep' in there, as a simple test, but if that is the problem - you'll need to check the DB startup and see where you've 'got to'.

Failing that, you can "attach" to your container interactively, with `docker exec -it <container> bash` and run the command and troubleshoot directly.

Comment: 'sleep 3' did the work. Thanks!
(I also removed 'it' from '-itd' as you suggested)

Comment: Next step might be figure out how you can 'detect' the port opening - you might find there's a log entry you can check for.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful advice.